# While printing the status of link list the programm is entring into infinte loop

Tags: c, data-structures

I have made a program of simple linked list and in this while i am printing the the values in linked list it is entering in the infinite loop.
i am hereby attaching the code.
I have made temp1 for traversal purpose.
'a' for storing the address of head node.
'temp' for creating new node.

```
// Creating a menu deriv en program of single link list
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
void main()
{
    struct node *a;
    char ch;
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *temp1;
    a=NULL;
    clrscr();
    do
    {
        if(a==NULL)
        {
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            printf("Enter Data");
            scanf("%d",&temp->data);
            temp->next=NULL;
            a=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            printf("Enter data element");
            scanf("%d",&temp->data);
            temp1=a;
            while(temp1->next!=NULL)
            {
                temp1=temp1->next;
            }
            temp1->next=temp;
        }
        printf("Do You Wish to continue");
        ch=getch();
    }
    while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');
    printf("Status of the link list");
    temp1=a;
    while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",temp1->data);
        temp1->next=temp1;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: probably changing `temp1->next=temp1;` with `temp1 = temp1->next;` will solve this issue. Also, you should free the allocated memory.

Comment: And also else-block need `temp->next=NULL;`

Comment: @Bob__Where I should make the change you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are doing two mistakes.

> 1st Mistake

After entering into `else` block u are not setting the `next` pointer of newly created node to `NULL`.So your code inside else should be like this...

```
else
        {
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->next=NULL;
        printf("Enter data element");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        temp1=a;
        while(temp1->next!=NULL)
            {
            temp1=temp1->next;
            }
        temp1->next=temp;
        }
```

> 2nd Mistake

While trying to print the linked list,inside the `while loop` the advancement of traversal pointer is wrong.So your code to print `linked list` should be this ...

```
while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%d ",temp1->data);
    temp1=temp1->next;
    }
```

Try to visualize the situation by drawing the situation on a paper,then it will be more clear to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got my Mistake Thanks for sparing me the time and guiding me